# If my algorithm has complexity O(n!*n), can I just write O(n!), or do I have to keep it like O(n!*n)?

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

Just as I asked in the title: if my algorithm has complexity $O(n!\times n)$, can I just write $O(n!)$, or I have to keep it like $O(n!\times n)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $n! \cdot n$ grows faster than $n!$, so it is not the case that $n! \cdot n$ is $O(n!)$. Therefore if all you know about an algorithm is that it runs in time $O(n! \cdot n)$, you cannot conclude that it runs in time $O(n!)$.

What you can do is "O tilde" notation, and write $\tilde{O}(n!)$. The meaning of "O tilde" is not completely standard, so you will have to explain that for you, $\tilde{O}$ suppresses factors which are polynomial in $n$.

Comment: Thank you for the info! The "O tilde" seems useful.

Answer (score 2):

No. You can't. As $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n!}{n! \times n} = 0 $. Hence, $n! \times n  = \omega(n!)$ or $n! = o(n\times n!)$ (little-oh).

Answer (score 1):

If you care about the actual sizes, you need to keep the $n$. You could switch to $O((n+1)!)$ if that is easier for you.

But maybe you only actually care about how fast the logarithm grows, and $\log(n!) = O(\log (n \cdot n!))$.

Comment: I guess you mean that $\log (n\,n!)=O(\log n!)$. What you've written is true but kinda the wrong way around.

Comment: You’re right, but once you take the logarithm many things become right because they turn into constants or small differences.

Comment: It seems the log made removing $n$ possible, but only possible when there is log